# Unable to format a dynamically created Quarto callout correctly

Tags: r, quarto

I am attempting to create a callout in a quarto document dynamically.  I can create the callout, but Quarto appears to overwrite my formatting instructions.

I can use Quarto commands to create a static callout that is correctly formatted:

```
::: {.callout-important}

This is the first hard-coded warning.

:::
```

which produces

[image]

as I expect.  Inspecting this element of the HTML document reveals the following HTML:

[image]

When I copy and paste this output, either into the body of a Quarto document, or into a code chunk within the same document and then render the document, I see:

[image]

with corresponding HTML:

[image]

My original HTML has been modified during the rendering process.

Here is a MRE:

````
---
title: "Test"
format: html
editor: visual
---

::: {.callout-important}

This is the first hard-coded warning.

:::

```{r}
#| label: validation
#| echo: FALSE
#| results: asis
cat("
<div class=\"callout callout-style-default callout-important callout-titled\">
<div class=\"callout-header d-flex align-content-center\">
<div class=\"callout-icon-container\">
<i class=\"callout-icon\"></i>
</div>
<div class=\"callout-title-container flex-fill\">
Important
</div>
</div>
<div class=\"callout-body-container callout-body\">
<p>This is a dynamic warning.</p>
</div>
</div>    
")
```

<div class="callout callout-style-default callout-important callout-titled">
<div class="callout-header d-flex align-content-center">
<div class="callout-icon-container">
<i class="callout-icon"></i>
</div>
<div class="callout-title-container flex-fill">
Important
</div>
</div>
<div class="callout-body-container callout-body">
<p>This is the second hard-coded warning.</p>
</div>
</div>
````

In addition,

```
cat("::: {.callout-important}\\n\\n This is the second dynamic callout. \\n\\n ::: \\n\\n")
```

and similar also do not work.

Can anyone help me dynamically create a correctly formatted callout?

**Edit**

Following SamR's suggestion in comments,  this

````
```{=HTML}
<div class="callout callout-style-default callout-important callout-titled">
 <div class="callout-header d-flex align-content-center">
 <div class="callout-icon-container">
 <i class="callout-icon"></i>
 </div>
 <div class="callout-title-container flex-fill">
 Important
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="callout-body-container callout-body">
 <p>This is the second hard-coded warning.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 ```
````

Produces the desired output, but remains static, so doesn't fully solve my problem.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with "dynamic"? What is your expected output?

Comment: Ultimately, I would like to control the type of the call out (note/warning/important etc) its title and content.  I didn't include that in the MRE as it doesn't seem relevant to the problem of the HTML being modified during the rendering process.  In terms of this question, my expected output is a callout that is identical in appearance to that generated by the quarto `::: {.callout-important}

This is the first hard-coded warning.

:::`.  Of course, the text within the three callouts in my examples varies ...

Comment: Have you tried the answer to [How to add HTML code to a Quarto website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74445505/how-to-add-html-code-to-a-quarto-website)? i.e. using an `{=html}` block?

Comment: @SamR:  Thank you.  I hadn't found that answer.  The suggested solution works when I wrap  the raw HTML in my MRE in ` \`\`\`{=HTML}` and ` \`\`\` `.  I've not yet found a way to get it to work with the code chunk labelled "validation".  It simply echoes the raw HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a second option which also makes use of a custom function to add a callout block directly to the document (and in contrast to what you have tried does not escape the line breaks, i.e. I use `\n` instead of `\\n`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{r}
#| echo: FALSE
my_callout <- function(type, x) {
  sprintf(
    paste(
      "::: {.callout-%s}",
      "This is the %s dynamic callout.",
      ":::",
      sep = "\n\n"
    ),
    type, x
  ) |> 
    cat()
}
```

```{r}
#| echo: FALSE
#| results: asis
my_callout("important", "SECOND")

```

```{r}
#| echo: FALSE
#| results: asis
my_callout("note", "THIRD")
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [`knitr::knit_child()`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html). We can create a function that generates different types of warning depending on the value of the argument passed to it:

````r
generate_callout <- function(x, show_note = TRUE) {
    callout_type <- symnum(
        x,
        cutpoints = c(0, 5, 10, Inf),
        symbols = c("note", "warning", "important")
    )
    callout_prefix <- ifelse(callout_type == "note", "Note: ", "Warning: ")

    # Don't show note at all
    if (!show_note & callout_type == "note") {
        return(invisible(NULL))
    }

    knitr::knit_child(text = c(
        "```{=html}",
        sprintf("<div class=\"callout callout-style-default callout-%s callout-titled\">", callout_type),
        "<div class=\"callout-header d-flex align-content-center\">
        <div class=\"callout-icon-container\">
        <i class=\"callout-icon\"></i>
        </div>
        <div class=\"callout-title-container flex-fill\">
        Important
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"callout-body-container callout-body\">",
        sprintf("<p>%sx is %s.</p>", callout_prefix, x),
        "</div>
        </div>",
        "```",
        "\n"
    ), quiet = TRUE) |> cat()
}
````

This will now generate the callouts as desired:

````
```{r}
#| echo: FALSE
#| results: asis
generate_callout(1)
generate_callout(1, show_note = FALSE)
generate_callout(10)
generate_callout(100)
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @SamR.  This is good, but I am going to accept Stefan's answer as theirs avoids the need to write raw HTML and instead relies on Quarto markdown.  That strikes me as more robust with respect to possible future changes in the rendering process.